# ActiveMQ Artemis web console missing columns

Tags: activemq-artemis

My ActiveMQ Artemis web console is showing all queues and topics, but lacks the detail I have seen on other deployments of the console. There are no columns present showing queue detail. The user role is `amq` and has the full permissions. I include a screenshot:

[image]

The `management.xml` is as follows:

```xml
<management-context xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">
<!--<connector connector-port="1099"/>-->
<authorisation>
   <allowlist>
      <entry domain="hawtio"/>
   </allowlist>
   <default-access>
      <access method="list*" roles="amq"/>
      <access method="get*" roles="amq"/>
      <access method="is*" roles="amq"/>
      <access method="set*" roles="amq"/>
      <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
   </default-access>
   <role-access>
      <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
         <access method="list*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="get*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="is*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="set*" roles="amq"/>
         <!-- Note count and browse are need to access the browse tab in the console-->
         <access method="browse*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="count*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
      </match>
      <!--example of how to configure a specific object-->
      <!--<match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis" key="subcomponent=queues">
         <access method="list*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
         <access method="get*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
         <access method="is*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
         <access method="set*" roles="update,amq"/>
         <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
      </match>-->
   </role-access>
</authorisation>
```

Here's `artemis.profile`:

```
ARTEMIS_HOME='/opt/apache-artemis-2.20.0'
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE='/var/lib/artemis'
ARTEMIS_DATA_DIR='/var/lib/artemis/data'
ARTEMIS_ETC_DIR='/var/lib/artemis/etc'
ARTEMIS_OOME_DUMP='/var/lib/artemis/log/oom_dump.hprof'

# The logging config will need an URI
# this will be encoded in case you use spaces or special characters
# on your directory structure
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_URI='file:/var/lib/artemis/'
ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI='file:/var/lib/artemis/etc/'

# Cluster Properties: Used to pass arguments to ActiveMQ Artemis which can be referenced in broker.xml
#ARTEMIS_CLUSTER_PROPS="-Dactivemq.remoting.default.port=61617 -Dactivemq.remoting.amqp.port=5673 -Dactivemq.remoting.stomp.port=61614 -Dactivemq.remoting.hornetq.port=5446"

# Hawtio Properties
HAWTIO_ROLE='amq'

# Java Opts
if [ -z "$JAVA_ARGS" ]; then
 JAVA_ARGS="-javaagent:/opt/jmx-exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=9404:/opt/jmx-exporter/etc/jmx-exporter-config.yaml -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1098 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 -XX:+PrintClassHistogram -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication   -Dhawtio.disableProxy=true -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.offline=true -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal -Djolokia.policyLocation=${ARTEMIS_INSTANCE_ETC_URI}jolokia-access.xml "
fi

# Uncomment to enable logging for Safepoint JVM pauses
#
# In addition to the traditional GC logs you could enable some JVM flags to know any meaningful and "hidden" pause
# that could affect the latencies of the services delivered by the broker, including those that are not reported by
# the classic GC logs and dependent by JVM background work (eg method deoptimizations, lock unbiasing, JNI, counted
# loops and obviously GC activity).
#
# Replace "all_pauses.log" with the file name you want to log to.
# JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 $JAVA_ARGS -XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1 -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:LogFile=all_pauses.log"

# Uncomment to enable the dumping of the Java heap when a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception is thrown
# JAVA_ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=50 $JAVA_ARGS -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=${ARTEMIS_OOME_DUMP}"

# Only enable debug options for the 'run' command
if [ "$1" = "run" ]; then :
    # Uncomment to enable remote debugging
    # DEBUG_ARGS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"

    # Uncomment for async profiler
    # DEBUG_ARGS="-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints"
fi
```

Here's `login.config`:

```
activemq {
    org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
           debug=false
           reload=true
           org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
           org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
}
```

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that in your screenshot you're looking at an address not a queue.

Comment: ok login.cofig is simpile ..pointing to users & roles - using the propertiesloginmodule - role is amq

Comment: All the configuration looks in order. Can you work up a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and share it?